# How to get formatted value and unit back from Measurement

Tags: swift, swift3, units-of-measurement

I'm trying to get the formatted value from a measurement and the units as two separate strings. I've written the function below to do this. I'm struggling with the function format for the extension to handle the template.

This doesn't work:

```
func getFormattedValueAndUnitFromMeasurement( measurement: Measurement<Unit> )
```

The following works but then I need to define the function for each unit type.

```
func getFormattedValueAndUnitFromMeasurement( measurement: Measurement<UnitLength> )
```

Here is the code I'm using.

```
var diameter: Measurement<UnitLength> = Measurement<UnitLength>( value: 13, unit: .inches)

let diameterFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
diameterFormatter.unitStyle = .medium
diameterFormatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit // .natural
diameterFormatter.numberFormatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
diameterFormatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1

    // Get the formatted text for the value and the units
let diameterText = diameterFormatter.getFormattedValueAndUnitFromMeasurement( measurement: diameter )


extension MeasurementFormatter {
    func getFormattedValueAndUnitFromMeasurement( measurement: Measurement<Unit> ) -> ( valueString: String, unitString: String)
    {
        // Number Formatter
        let numberFormatter = self.numberFormatter

        // This assumes the number is going to be displayed in the provided units. Ok for now
        let numberString = numberFormatter?.string( from: NSNumber (value: measurement.value) )

        // Figure out just the units of the string
        var units: String = self.string( for: measurement)!

        if ( units.hasPrefix(numberString!) ) {
            units.removeSubrange((numberString?.startIndex)! ..< (numberString?.index((numberString?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: (numberString?.characters.count)! ))!)
        }

        return ( numberString!, units)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Measurement<Unit>` and `Measurement<UnitLength>` are considered to be two different types, like `String` and `Int`. You should use generics to work with the desired types, e.g.

```
func getFormattedValueAndUnitFromMeasurement<T>( measurement: Measurement<T> )       
                                              -> ( valueString: String, unitString: String)
```